# information extraction of NAMED ENTITIES python 2.7

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I have a text that looks like:

```
"<ENAMEX TYPE="PERSON">Edward R. Kimmel</ENAMEX>, one of Admiral <ENAMEX TYPE="PERSON">Jack</ENAMEX>'s two surviving sons and..."
```

I want an output as the following:

PERSON Edward R. Kimmel

PERSON Jack

Any idea using RegEX?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Since you are using Python, why not use `ElementTree` to parse the XML?

Comment: I will look into this to find an answer, thanks. I have never used it before !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try beautifulsoup?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
txt = """<ENAMEX TYPE="PERSON">Edward R. Kimmel</ENAMEX>, one of Admiral <ENAMEX TYPE="PERSON">Jack</ENAMEX>'s twosurviving sons and..."""
soup = BeautifulSoup(txt,"html.parser")
for i in soup.findAll(attrs={'type' : 'PERSON'}):
    print(i.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `.findall`

```
import re
x = '"<ENAMEX TYPE="PERSON">Edward R. Kimmel</ENAMEX>, one of Admiral <ENAMEX TYPE="PERSON">Jack</ENAMEX>"'
mac = []
mac = re.findall("TYPE=\"PERSON\">(.+?)<",x)


for i in mac:
    print "PERSON "+i
```